# Swift WatchOS 2.0 Haptics implementation issues

Tags: ios, swift, swift2, xcode7, haptic-feedback

So I've made a very simple iOS app in SWiFT for the sake of experimentation that displays a string at the touch of a button I've successfully implemented and tested the watchOS version and it runs fine on my devices. What I want to do is add haptic .Click to the button in the watch app. Now I did some research and it says in ever article "it's easy just call it like this"

i started by Importing the WatchKit as stated in posts such as [Where to find Taptic feedback API documentation or capabilities for watchOS 2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31300036/ios-watchos2-where-to-find-taptic-feedback-api-documentation-or-capabilities)

```
import UIKit
import WatchKit


class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var Button1: UIButton!

    @IBOutlet weak var LabelView: UILabel!


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }


    @IBAction func ButtonPressed(sender: UIButton) {

// Directly Call the function in the Action     
WKInterfaceDevice.currentDevice().playHaptic(.Click)

    var myString = “Hello, World!”

        LabelView.text = “\(myString)”

    }
}
```

If this is the case (which I'm guessing it is not) then there is something wrong with my machine, or much more likely my code is wrong and more importantly I haven't understood the topic.

When I try to build the above example it fails at the Haptics line with the error:

```
"playHaptic" is unavailable.
```

This is screaming include issues but I have

```
Import WatchKit
```

So I thought I was good and I'm forcing the .Click parameter so it looks ok but I've only been doing this a week so please forgive my lack of knowledge.

ANY AND ALL COMMENTS AND HELP ARE HUGELY APPRECIATED AS EVER!

I look forward to hearing from you all :)

EDIT:

iv also just read and experimented with the example [HERE](https://github.com/shu223/watchOS-2-Sampler/blob/master/watchOS2Sampler%20WatchKit%20Extension/TapticInterfaceController.swift) but when i try and repurpose it in my app its not happening.

i get the same errors like the libraries are not accessible.

do i need to import with the bridging method instead of directly in my swift file?

Comment: Someone just mentioned that if i change my frameworks from iOS to WatchOs then i may have better luck, i have very little experience but tried converting it, but i needed to change the way the label is updated as LableView.text is not on in watchKit
can i set it to `LabelView.setText("\(myString)")` ?? still though now only using the WK frameworks only having changed all my `IBactions` from `UIButton` to `WKInterfaceButton` and all my labels from  `UILabel` to `WKInterfaceLabel ` as all i need is to set the string its very simple but i still get the error every time it reaches the haptic call

Comment: If you look at the second example you linked, the taptic interface controller is running on the watch, not the phone.  A phone isn't making the watch vibrate.  You say you're making a watch app, but you're posting code for phone app.

Answer (score 0):

You're getting watchOS and iOS mixed up here.  There's no  `playHaptic` method on an iOS device.

While `WKInterfaceDevice` is available on iOS, [its iOS methods](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/WatchKit/Reference/WKInterfaceDevice_class/#//apple_ref/occ/clm/WKInterfaceDevice/currentDevice) are different from [its watchOS methods](https://developer.apple.com/library/watchos/documentation/WatchKit/Reference/WKInterfaceDevice_class/#//apple_ref/occ/clm/WKInterfaceDevice/currentDevice).

The `playHaptic` method will work fine in your watch extension, but not in an iOS view controller.

*If you're trying to activate taptic feedback on your watch when you press a button on your phone, you need to look into Watch Connectivity.*

Comment: if i directly swap out the `UILabel` and `UIButton` for `WKInterfaceLabel` and `WKInterfaceButton` i can no longer access the .text variable of `WKInterfaceLabel` so i cant update the string after press. also im still geting a flag at the `playHaptic` line